# Why couldn't i insert the same element into an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a array of objects. But when I insert the object the I previously added, it will override my previous object. how can I solve it?

I have on object called player. In player, I have two array : one called onHandWeapon, one called onFieldWeapon. They are array of weapon object.

```
function player(lp){
        this.lp = lp;
        this.onFieldWeapon = new Array();
        this.onHandWeapon = new Array();

    } 

function weapon(id, heart, bullet, src){
            this.id = id;
            this.heart = heart;
            this.bullet = bullet;
            this.src = src;
            this.location;
            this.name;
            this.discription;
            this.bufferBullet = bullet;
    }
```

I have set three dummy object in onHandWeapon array. Then I want to randomly pick up one of them and put it into onFieldWeapon and assign a random location to it.

```
 function aiCreateWeapon(){
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*ai.onHandWeapon.length);
        $('#console').append(' ' + b + ' ');
        var ip = 100;

        while($('#'+ip).attr('class') != 'enemyField'){
            ip = Math.floor(Math.random()*48);
        }

        encurrentWeapon = ai.onHandWeapon[b];

        var source = encurrentWeapon.src;

        var oImg = document.createElement("img");
        oImg.setAttribute('src', source);
        oImg.setAttribute('height', '60px');
        oImg.setAttribute('width', '60px');
        $('#'+ip).append(oImg).show('explode','slow');

        encurrentWeapon.location = ip;  
        ai.onFieldWeapon.push( encurrentWeapon);

        $('#console').append(' ' + ai.onFieldWeapon[0].location + ' ');
}
```

aiCreateWeapon is a function bind to a button. When I click it, the ai.onFieldWeapon[0].location is a fixed location until it changes. I have check that every time when the object which is same as the first element, is added to the onFieldWeapon Array, it will override the first element's data.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but I noticed that push encurrentWeapon to the array, and write to console always item at 0 index. Probably you should access ai.onFieldWeapon[ai.onFieldWeapon.length - 1] item.

Comment: I tried this but not gonna work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you post the code where you create player object?

Comment: oh,my God,what is it ?encurrentWeapon in function aiCreateWeapon ,is a global variable!

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the same object into an array multiple times, you'll have multiple entries in the array that are all references to the same underlying object. In the following example all three entries in `myArray` and the `x` and `y` and `myObj` variables all point to the same underlying object, so if you change the properties of the object via one of the array items it's not that it updates the other array items too, it is that the other array items point to the same object you just changed:

```
var myObj = { "p1" : "v1", "p2" : "v2" };
var myArray = [];
// all of the following reference the same underlying object as myObj,
// not copies of myObj.
myArray.push(myObj);
myArray.push(myObj);
myArray.push(myObj);
var x = myObj,
    y = myObj;
myArray[1].p1 = "new value";
alert(myArray[0].p1); // "new value"
alert(x.p1); // "new value"
```

It sounds like what you want to do is create a *copy* of the object each time so that each item in the array is an independent object that you can update without affecting all the others. Unfortunately there is no built-in way to do that in JavaScript. Fortunately it's not particularly difficult to write your own object copying function, especially in your case where you seem to have only a one-dimensional object:

```
function copyObject(srcObj) {
   // create new blank object and copy the direct properties one by one
   var newObj = {};
   for (var k in srcObj)
      if (srcObj.hasOwnProperty(k))
          newObj[k] = srcObj[k];
   return newObj;
}

var myObj = { "p1" : "v1", "p2" : "v2" };
var myArray = [];
// make independent copies instead of just more references to the same object
myArray.push(copyObject(myObj));
myArray.push(copyObject(myObj));
myArray.push(copyObject(myObj));
var x = copyObject(myObj),
    y = copyObject(myObj);
myArray[1].p1 = "new value";
alert(myArray[0].p1); // "v1"
```

If you have objects that contain objects or arrays then your `copyObject()` function needs to be more complicated - usually some form of recursion would be used.